# When do I need to make a tax payment on money I receive once a year as a member of an LLC?

Tags: united-states, taxes

I will receive a one time distribution from an LLC that I am a member of in July, 2020. When and how do I need to pay taxes on this money? I don't receive any other income from the LLC throughout the year.

Comment: Do you have other income?  If so, is it W2 or 1099?

Comment: Did this LLC elect to be taxed as a corporation, or if in the first year of operation will it do so when it files, and if so which type, and is the 'distribution' because you did work (formally, performed services)? See [IRS pub 3402](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p3402)